# CSS transparent cut-out

Tags: css, responsive

Received a two column layout design for a website. Each column has a transparent background that, combined, forms a curved cut-out at the top.

I need the columns to grow with content, however this distorts the background image when set on background-size: cover (Matching things up in order to use repeat-y won't work either).  Is there a good way to accomplish this, or a way to tell him absolutely not?

```
.middle-left-container {
  float: left;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('/tlm-wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/left-menu-background-sliced.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  width: 20%;
}

body:not(.home) .middle-left-container {
 top: 0;
 background-image: url('/tlm-wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/left- menu-main.png');
}


.middle-right-container {
 float: left;
 min-height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-image: url('/tlm-wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/banner-bg.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 80%;
}

body:not(.home) .middle-right-container {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: you may use border-radius, overflow and background-size http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNbGeV

Comment: Forgot to say thanks, this is just what I was looking for and was trying to do.. Didn't know the end part of border-radius: x x x x /xem; !

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the curved bg image on the `<body>`, put it on a fixed-width container, then anchor the bg-image position.

```
.container {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-position: top center;
    ...
}
```

Then inside that container, put each of your column containers. Something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-nav"> ... </div>
    <div class="middle-left-container"> ... </div>
    <div class="middle-right-container"> ... </div>
</div>
```